# Where to find MSP430 & CC430 code examples?

Tags: msp430, library

I was googling for some MSP430 code examples (e.g. for SPI) for some time, unable to find anything. Do you happen to know, where to find some examples? They do have some on TI webpage, but very general, and not many of them.

Answer (score 2):

MSP340 is a huge family with a few different non-code-compatible serial communication modules. You'll need to figure out which sub-family you're using and check the [code examples page](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontrollers_16-bit_32-bit/msp/tools_software.page#code) at TI for that device. The [MSPWare package](http://www.ti.com/tool/mspware) also has a lot of examples.

Beyond that it's usually a good bet to start with the evaluation module pages for the chip you're looking at and look for example code there.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of examples if you a search msp430 code examples spi I got tons of valid results like this one [tutorial](http://www.argenox.com/library/msp430/msp430-spi-peripheral-chapter-9/).   Of course you have to tailor the pin settings to the parts you have but the ideas are the same.